# How could I reduce uncovered branches in this code contains std::string operator+?

Tags: c++, googletest, gcov, lcov

I'm using lcov2.0 to check my test branch coverage, with encounter this issue.

```cpp
// source code
void test_string_plus(const string& local ,const string& remote)
{
    static string recv_msg;
    static_cast<void>(recv_msg.assign("/" + (local < remote ? local + "_" + remote : remote + "_" + local)));
}
// test code
TEST(teststring, teststringplus)
{
    string local = "test1";  
    string remote = "test12";
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(test_string_plus(local, remote));
    local = "test21";
    remote = "test2";  
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(test_string_plus(local, remote));
}
```

It reports like this in lcov

```
     281                 :           2 : void test_string_plus(const string& local ,const string& remote)
     282                 :             : {
     283                 :           2 :     static string recv_msg;
     284   [ +  +  +  -  :           2 :     static_cast<void>(recv_msg.assign("/" + (local < remote ? local + "_" + remote : remote + "_" + local)));
          +  -  +  -  +  
          -  +  -  +  +  
          +  +  -  -  -  
                      - ]
     285                 :           2 : }
```

gcov file shows that this code contains a lot of uncovered branches with throw.

```
        2:  284:    static_cast<void>(recv_msg.assign("/" + (local < remote ? local + "_" + remote : remote + "_" + local)));
call    0 returned 2
branch  1 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch  2 taken 1
call    3 returned 1
branch  4 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch  5 taken 0 (throw)
call    6 returned 1
branch  7 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch  8 taken 0 (throw)
call    9 returned 1
branch 10 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch 11 taken 0 (throw)
call   12 returned 1
branch 13 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch 14 taken 0 (throw)
call   15 returned 2
branch 16 taken 2 (fallthrough)
branch 17 taken 0 (throw)
call   18 returned 2
call   19 returned 2
call   20 returned 2
branch 21 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch 22 taken 1
call   23 returned 1
branch 24 taken 1 (fallthrough)
branch 25 taken 1
call   26 returned 1
call   27 never executed
branch 28 never executed
branch 29 never executed
call   30 never executed
branch 31 never executed
branch 32 never executed
call   33 never executed
        2:  285:}
```

tools version and command I used.

- g++/gcov (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
- gtest 1.12.x
- lcov/genhtml: LCOV version 2.0-1

```
    g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fprofile-update=atomic && \
    ./test && \
    gcov -b -c -o . test.cpp && \
    lcov --capture \
         --rc branch_coverage=1 \
         --directory . \
         --filter branch \
         --output-file coverage_all.info \
         --ignore-errors mismatch && \
    genhtml coverage_all.info \
            --rc branch_coverage=1 \
            --output-directory coverage_report && \
    rm *.info
```

I already used `--filter branch` to ignore some unreachable branches

---

How should I reduce the uncovered branches here? Or can I just ignore them?

https://legacy.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/

I checkout reference of `operator+()` in std::string.
It seems that an exception will only be thrown when attempting to add a string that exceeds the length limit or when the memory application fails, but in practical projects, constructing such test conditions is very unreasonable.

---

I tried to modify `?:` to if else, those branches caused by string can be filter.

```
    281                 :           2 : void test_string_plus(const string& local ,const string& remote)
     282                 :             : {
     283                 :           2 :     static string recv_msg;
     284                 :           2 :     string target("/");
     285         [ +  + ]:           2 :     if(local<remote)
     286                 :             :     {
     287                 :           1 :         target += local + "_" + remote;
     288                 :             :     }
     289                 :             :     else{
     290                 :           1 :         target +=  remote + "_" + local;
     291                 :             :     }
     292                 :           2 :     static_cast<void>(recv_msg.assign(target));
```

Comment: What's the golden rule of testing? Test your own code, not 3rd party libraries. If you write a test for a 3rd party library - and that includes STL that belongs upstream and nowhere else. That be said, using gcov and then getting hung up in the STL is not a good way to go. You are right about the exception, but even `std::string` is more complicated than you'd be able to cover this easily.

Comment: THX. I understand what you mean, so I'm planning to lower branch coverage requirements. At present, it seems impossible to achieve 100% branch coverage even with `--filter branch`.

Comment: Global `using namespace std;` is bad. It's quite possible that you trigger the analyzer by omitting those `std::`(it's hard to track) or something simply compiles wrong - combining that with extensive macros system or large codebase often creates unexpected results.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Thx, I am doing this because the posted code is only used for LCOV testing and is not the actual project code.using namespace std is only for the convenience of writing test code.

Comment: oh! I ran into odd untracesble problem like that once, since that time I write test stuff using own dictionary of types (e.g. `using String = std::string;`). thing about `std::string`.... it _does_ throw at least when reallocating or when going from small object to regular. having alternate non-throwing allocators or optimizing operations where may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to modify `?:` to if else, those branches caused by string can be filter by lcov `--filter branch` options

```
    281                 :           2 : void test_string_plus(const string& local ,const string& remote)
     282                 :             : {
     283                 :           2 :     static string recv_msg;
     284                 :           2 :     string target("/");
     285         [ +  + ]:           2 :     if(local<remote)
     286                 :             :     {
     287                 :           1 :         target += local + "_" + remote;
     288                 :             :     }
     289                 :             :     else{
     290                 :           1 :         target +=  remote + "_" + local;
     291                 :             :     }
     292                 :           2 :     static_cast<void>(recv_msg.assign(target));
```